# How to permanently override JS DOM API in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

Suppose I am building a new web browser, but want to intercept calls to certain JS functions such as window.fetch() and XMLHttpRequest and postMessage, to PREVENT a certain iframe in a domain to get information in and out.

If I simply override these objects, can’t the subsequent JS code simply call delete window.fetch to remove my overrides? Is there a way to freeze the object or property to prevent this in modern mobile browsers, or intercept calls using native code?

On Android Chrome, there seems to be a native way to do that: https://www.codevog.com/blog/2015-03-09-webview-interactions-with-javascript

How can I do it in Android and iOS?

PS: I know I can intercept requests but how do I intercept function calls like postMessage?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna advice this but you can try a monkey patch:

```
XMLHttpRequest = (function(xhtp){
    //do something with xhtp
    //someAPI(xhtp)...
    return null;//or whatever you want
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

I just wrote this ad-hoc. You need to make sure all entry points to that object is patched like above. Within the iief pass it to your API. Twitter does this for console.log, they probably return an empty function

Comment: But the delete keyword would just remove it.

Comment: There is a reason why monkey patch is used. Delete would remove it? Yes, perhaps you want to use it before that, or even modify the behavior other then removing so that your window will be notified when someone else calls it. Btw, there is not fiddle to demonstrate a case you want to achieve. So what is it? Prevent iframe from a domain to access your window? Why not use the x-frame-origin header etc? For the post message, you cannot modify it if you are not in control of the iframe, but the API always gives you control on which messages to care about using event.origin.

Comment: I want to override a property and prevent the delete keyword from undoing it and using previously existing property or method.

Comment: `window.originalObject = {a:2}
window.originalObject = (function(originalObject){
 Object.defineProperty(
  window,
  "originalObject",
        {
   enumerable:false,
   configurable:false,
   get:function(){
    return originalObject;
            }
        }
 );
 return window.originalObject;
})(window.originalObject)`

Also consider using Object.freeze and Object.seal in modern browsers. Change the getter function to make it behave however you want

Comment: What was the point of using the IIFE here? It prevents delete keyword?

Comment: you can return something within the get/set/value of the property descriptor that depends on the originalObject, because Object.defineProperty will override it.

Comment: That’s excellent, just use defineProperty with configurable: false and writable: false right?

Comment: yes. If you use get or set, you don't have to specify write -->https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty